# Button On Bootstrap Nav bar

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

[image: screenshot]

I'm using React and gotten the above with

```
    <Nav bsStyle="tabs">
      <NavItem active>Nav Item 1</NavItem>
      <NavItem>Nav Item 2</NavItem>
      {this.renderAdvancedSettingsButton()}
    </Nav>
```

But this gives a warning about unknown props as `Button` is not meant to be nested inside `Nav`.

What's the proper way to do this? If i set `Nav`'s css to `float:left`, the thin line will end at the last `NavItem` instead of the entire width, and other components apart from the button will move to the right of the `Nav` bar.

Comment: What is the specific prop error? 
Ultimately it's probably just saying you provided a prop, like `bsStyle` but didn't declare it within that component. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: `Warning: Unknown props \`activeKey\`, \`activeHref\` on <button> tag.` I'm guessing `Nav` has these props and it get passed to `Button`? It's just a warning, still ugly though.